Does the orbital plane that contains the trajectories of 2 bodies pass through the center of mass of each of the bodies?
Two bodies that attract each other gravitationally will move in a conic trajectory with respect to the center of mass of both. A conic is the meeting of a cone and a plane thus it is always a plane movement with respect to the center of mass of the system. My question is: does this plane pass through the individual centers of mass of the two bodies? I know that usually the two bodies are way smaller than the trajectory and can be approximated by points, but I'm interested in the math problem.

Have you made in effort to find a contrary case? Do you think it requires that the center of mass and center of gravity be the same point, because that is certainly not generally true. Do you think a center of gravity can even be defined for arbitrary mass distribution in any field configuration that satisfies Newton's laws?

If we assume that Newtonian mechanics is perfect (i.e., we are ignoring the effects of General Relativity), then yes the plane will pass through the center of mass of both bodies.
